# How to implement triggering "revert" when draggable-element is over "margin" of droppable element. jQuery

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I need that "revert" triggering when element $('.ship') is over other $('.ship') element or over "margin" of $('.ship'). It works over "padding" and "border", but don't work over "margin". How do I do this? Here is the piece of my code:

```
$('.ship').draggable({
    containment : "#content",
    snap : "#board table td",
    snapMode : "inner",
    revert : "invalid",
    opacity: 0.7,
    stack: '.ship',
});

$('.ship').droppable({
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', true);
    },
    tolerance: 'touch'
});

$('#board').droppable({
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).css('margin', '3px');
        ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
    },
    tolerance: 'fit'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the direct answer but if you can't find a way to work with margins, wrap a container around .ship, occupy the same area as your current margin would and make that container droppable.